# What is the difference between these two implementations of push_front function for dynamically allocated array? (malloc vs realloc)

Tags: arrays, c, memory-management

Can you explain why exactly the first function doesn't work correctly?

I wrote two identical functions:

```
bool push_front(int value, size_t *size, int **arr) {
    if (!*arr) return false;
    int *new_arr = realloc(*arr, sizeof(int[*size + 1]));
    if (!new_arr) return false;
    new_arr[0] = value;
    for (size_t i = 1, j = 0; j < *size; ++i, ++j)
        new_arr[i] = (*arr)[j];
    ++*size;
    *arr = new_arr;
    return true;
}

bool push_front(int value, size_t *size, int **arr) {
    if (!*arr) return false;
    int *new_arr = malloc(sizeof(int[*size + 1]));
    if (!new_arr) return false;
    new_arr[0] = value;
    for (size_t i = 1, j = 0; j < *size; ++i, ++j)
        new_arr[i] = (*arr)[j];
    ++*size;
    free(*arr);
    *arr = new_arr;
    return true;
}
```

The first one does add an element, but it's also rewriting all the array elements to 'value'. Any ideas why it happens?

Comment: How do you instantiate the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first approach using `realloc` has multiple problems:

- if the array is empty, you might want to allocate a singleton even if `*arr` is null, hence you should only fail if `*arr` is null **and** if `*size` is not. As suggested by *@Fe2O3*, you can still use `realloc` if `*arr` is null because `realloc(NULL, size)` is equivalent to `malloc(size)` .
- you overwrite the first element before shifting the elements one position to the right
- you read `(*arr)[i]` after reallocating the array: `*arr` may be an invalid pointer if the block was reallocated to a different address, this has undefined behavior.
- you copy the elements the first to the last one position to the right: each element is overwritten before it is copied, resulting in all elements receiving the same value `value`.

Here is a modified version:

```
bool push_front(int value, size_t *size, int **arr) {
    if (!*arr && *size)
        return false;
    int *new_arr = realloc(*arr, sizeof(int[*size + 1]));
    if (!new_arr)
        return false;
    for (size_t i = *size; i > 0; i--)
        new_arr[i] = new_arr[i - 1];
    new_arr[0] = value;
    ++*size;
    *arr = new_arr;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the answer by @chqrlie, the code in version1 "*overwrites the first element before shifting the elements one position to the right*" and then obliterates other values by replicating in the wrong direction (left to right).

Your second version "works" because the code instantiates a completely separate array (hope you have lots of RAM), then transfers values to it *in the correct sequence!*.

(Interestingly, if required, `realloc()` may need to allocate a new block to accommodate a growing requirement, then copy all the values from the old to the new before releasing the old for re-use. Wouldn't it be nice if there was a `reallocFront()` that would do the grunt work behind the scenes for you?)

There is no obvious reason this function should reject putting the first element into the array.

Below is another solution:

```
bool push_front( int value, size_t *size, int **arr ) {
    int *new_arr = realloc( *arr, (*size + 1) * sizeof *arr );
    if( !new_arr ) return false;

    memmove( new_arr + 1, new_arr, *size * sizeof **arr ); // don't re-invent the wheel!
    *new_arr = value;

    ++*size;
    *arr = new_arr;
    return true;
}
```

If `*arr` is NULL, `realloc()` will act exactly like `malloc()`.

Spend time familiarising yourself with available, proven Standard Library functions.

Comment: I got bitten once too many a few months ago and it took such a painful debugging session to realize the mistake in code I had been staring at for hours... I no longer use naked `memset`, `memcpy` or `memmove` for arrays, I use macros that check the type compatibility and multiply the count by the size of the target element. This reduces the risk of miscomputed counts and actually improves code readability.

Comment: @chqrlie Ah... but you now miss out on that glorious feeling of accomplishment in finding that microscopic and understandable bug... `:-)`